# What is this symmetric simplex category, concretely?

Tags: ct.category-theory, simplicial-stuff, monoidal-categories, symmetric-groups

Let $\Delta_+$ denote the category of finite ordinal numbers with monotonic maps (the subscript indicates that $0$ is included, so this is the [augmented simplex category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplex+category)). This has a monoidal structure (given by the sum), which is not symmetric. But we can make it symmetric in a universal way, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117533/free-symmetric-monoidal-category-on-a-monoidal-category) for the general procedure. Let us denote this symmetric monoidal category by $(\Delta_+)_{\mathrm{sym}}$.

**Question.** What is a more "concrete" symmetric monoidal category which is equivalent to $(\Delta_+)_{\mathrm{sym}}$?

Notice that this is not the symmetric monoidal category $\mathcal{F}$ of finite sets. Whereas $(\Delta_+)_{\mathrm{sym}}$ classifies algebra objects in symmetric monoidal categories, $\mathcal{F}$ classifies commutative algebra objects in symmetric monoidal categories. Hence, there will be a strong symmetric monoidal functor $(\Delta_+)_{\mathrm{sym}} \to \mathcal{F}$, which is essentially surjective, but not fully faithful.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$\Delta_+$ is the monoidal category generated from the associative operad, considered as a non-symmetric operad. Similarly, $(\Delta_+)_{{\rm sym}}$ is the symmetric monoidal category generated from the associative operad, this time considered as a symmetric operad. This category can then be explicitly described as the category whose objects are finite sets and such that the morphisms from $I$ to $J$ are given by maps $f:I \to J$ together with, for each $j \in J$, a choice of a linear order on $f^{-1}(j)$. The symmetric monoidal structure is given by disjoint union.

Comment: I'll add that this is usually called the category of "noncommutative sets".

Comment: @DenisNardin: Thanks! Can you give a reference for this terminology?

Comment: @Yonatan Harpaz: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I guess that the composition of morphisms is defined as follows: For $i , i' \in (gf)^{-1}(k)$ we have $i < i'$ if either $f(i) < f(i')$ in $g^{-1}(k)$ or $f(i)=f(i')$ and $i < i'$ in $f^{-1}(f(i))$. Is this correct?

Comment: @HeinrichD, Exactly. Maybe I should have recalled the general construction. Given a (single colored) symmetric operad $P$, the symmetric monoidal category generated from $P$ has as objects the finite sets and the morphisms from $I$ to $J$ are given by maps $f: I \to J$ together with a choice, for each $j \in J$, of a multi-operation $\varphi \in P(f^{-1}(j))$ (here we think of the underlying data of $P$ as a functor from the groupoid of finite sets to sets) . Composition is then defined using the composition structure of the operad.

Comment: @HeinrichD The category itself was introduced by Fiedorowicz and Loday in "[Crossed simplicial groups and their associated homology](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1991-326-01/S0002-9947-1991-0998125-4/)". The name seems to be first used by Pirashvili in "[On the PROP corresponding to bialgebras](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=CTGDC_2002__43_3_221_0)"; see also "[Hochschild and Cyclic Homology via
Functor Homology](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Birgit_Richter/publication/226373583_Hochschild_and_Cyclic_Homology_via_Functor_Homology/links/55c9e1bd08aeb9756748e4ed.pdf)".

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Thank you, these references are very useful.

Comment: @HeinrichD Actually I've re-read Pirashvili's paper, and he points to "[Additive K-theory](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0078368)" by Feigin and Tsygan, page 191 for the first appearance of the category in question (they call it "Symmetric category" there)